# Do I need to migrate an action to v2 that doesn't use Dialogflow?

Tags: migration, actions-on-google

Google sent me a reminder to migrate from Dialogflow API v1 to v2. I don't use Dialogflow. The skill is connected to custom Python code on our own servers. Our code gets JSON and returns JSON. Should I be concerned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've described still could be using Dialogflow, since Actions using Dialogflow can also be written in Python and receive JSON.

Some things that might be indicators:

- If you have an `actions.json` file, and deploy this when you update your Action, you are probably *not* using Dialogflow.
- If the JSON you receive contains an attribute "result" or "originalRequest" (or both), then you're using Dialogflow's fulfillment webhook protocol.
- If you're looking at `inputs[0].intent` to see what Intent was triggered, and the value either matches one in your `actions.json` or a string such as `actions.intent.TEXT`, then you're using the Actions SDK and *not* Dialogflow.
- If you were looking at `result.metadata.intentName` to get the name of the Intent, then you're using Dialogflow.

If you *are* using Dialogflow, you need to move to v2, which will require some changes in the names of several of the JSON fields. https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v1-v2-migration-guide-fulfillment#webhook_request_and_response_json (and sections further down on the page) provide information on the changes and what you'll need to do.

Comment: Well, the skill is based on so-called “Actions SDK” (which is a misnomer, I'm not using any SDK, just a REST API), I do have `actions.json` file. I'm definitely not using Dialogflow consciously, but Google was trying so hard to push me to use it that I'm not quite certain if it's not used somewhere ‘by default’. For instance, I'm checking the value of `intent` to know if this is session-first message.

Comment: It sounds like you're not using Dialogflow. Google doesn't use it by default "somewhere". You're either using the Actions SDK or Dialogflow. I assume you're using the value of `inputs[0].intent` when you say you're checking the value of `intent`. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! you should be concerned, I have faced the same issue as JSON has been changed for somethings already.

Comment: Do you know any guide which would suit this situation? The guides sent by Google are quite misleading as they constantly refer to “Dialogflow” and it's hard to understand what it actually means